# Laravel model can't be named 'Match'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a model in Laravel  named 'Match'. When I try to do this, I get an error: `syntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting identifier`. When I add a character (for example: 'Matcha'), the error goes away.

[image]

I am using this code in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.12",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
```

I have tried to solve the problem, but I couldn't find any solutions on the internet.

Is there a way I can solve this error?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PHP 8 and [match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) is a reserved keyword in PHP 8.

Refer [reserved keywords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).